# Не удостоены / неудостоены

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Вы, сэр, не удостоены / неудостоены ни единой конфеты.

Я сомневаюсь, т. к., как знаем, *недостоин* пишется слитно.

> Косой заяц недостоин иметь хорошо наточённый серп.